# Syntax error renaming a .txt file using a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, rename

I want to **rename** a log file that is being created when executing another batch file.
But when I want to **execute** the batch file, it gives me a syntax error.

This is what I have written so far:

```
@echo off
rename C:\Users\SB\Dekstop\Schoolbestanden\"BackupLog.txt" Kippenei.txt
```

I have also tried to put the same code into the batch file that creates the log file but that creates an error saying: **'Cannot find BackupLog.txt'**

Google did not give me any useful information except that what I found, did not work for me.

I hope that someone can help me with this batch file.

**Edit**: I guess it was a case of backspacing **"BackupLog.txt"** because I did just that and it renamed BackupLog.txt to Kippenei.txt.

So what I have done now is:

```
@echo off

rename C:\Users\SB\Desktop\Schoolbestanden\"BackupLog.txt" Kippenei.txt
```

What remains now, is implementing the code into the batch file that uses **Robocopy** to backup my files.

But I can continue working now :)

**Edit 2**: Make sure that you use a **completely different name** than the source file.
Because it does **not** want to save the file if the destination filename contains even a **tiny bit** of the source filename.

So if you have any problem with renaming anything, try a different but logical name (instead of chicken egg like I did)
.

Comment: Are you sure the file name contains quotation marks (`"BackupLog.txt"`)? Try to remove them from the command.

Comment: It does contain Hyphens but one way or the other, it does not recognize what I am trying to execute.

Comment: it must be that your file BackupLog.txt does not exist in the directory you are specifying.

Comment: It does exist but I have to execute another batch file in order to create the .txt file.
I have found the solution and put it into the opening post.

Comment: I edited your question to properly format your code as code. I can't see any difference between your before and after code. It sounds to me like you had (have?) a timing issue. Perhaps the first time you ran the script, the file did not exist yet. By the time you ran it another time, the file had been created.

Comment: the second bat has a blank line that may solve the race situation. Just kidding of course :)

Comment: That moment when you are out of options and then....you solved it yourself by just trying different things (like pressing the backspace for 10 times and putting quotation marks everywhere xD).